# Can I add empty lines to Cognos list report?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

The customer wants to show empty line between each two lines with data in a list report,just like the following image.I want to know how can I achieve this in report studio? I know I can add empty data in the back, but it is not a good idea, because the 'view' should not affect 'model'.

Anybody can help me?

[image]

Comment: Do you know the number of rows? A simple alternative is just to adjust the padding between rows; this doesn't create a dummy row but would have the spacing. If you want every/other than it would be similar to the alternating rows technique.

Comment: @toddnappi padding should work,but I am wondering is there a way to set style or something to generate dummy row.

Comment: There is no built in functionality. You might be able to do it with a join to a dummy table but I can't think of a elegant solution which doesnt involve knowing the number of rows beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A somewhat awkward workaround by use of Section feature of List elements:

1. Select every column in List element, copy and paste into same List so you have two of each column.
2. Create a Section by selecting one of each column header in the List element, then click the Section button.
3. Unlock the formatting (padlock icon) and remove all the text items from inside the Section header. Then add a block element to the inside of the Section header (can apply Size and Formatting properties here if desired) and optionally remove the "Section Header Cell" Class of the Section List Cell to remove the line separator.
4. Set column titles as hidden in the bottom List element properties (you can hard-code column titles with a Table element if needed).

Voila! Blank lines in-between each row in your list element.

Comment: Since the answer wasn't accepted, I wanted to comment that it works for me. Also opens up a lot of options for breaking on data attributes. Thanks for coming back and answering this!

Answer (score 1):

Merge the cells.  Add a text item to the merged cell.  Add space to the text item.